# Android web view integrated inside SDK

Tags: android, android-webview

I am building some sort of SDK and I need to provide functionality to show a web page.

eg `MySdk.ShowPage(Activity activity)`

I have managed to show the page like this :

```
public void showPage(Activity activity) {
   

 

    activity.setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) ((Activity) activity).findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    /* WebSettings websettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(ScrollView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);*/

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
  }
```

However when I press back button or back gesture, it is ignored.

I know this is easily solved when WebView is an inner class of an Activity or working in a normal app where you can get the activity from a fragment and etc, then override onBackPressed() but in my case I cannot do that.

I have an app without any activates, working as an SDK.

Any ideas how to enable back button to close the webView ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

I have created an empty activity without any layout or UI, onCreate of that activity call to show WebView.

In that activity I have access to onKeyDown and can identify action to back button.